# Generate Natural Logarithm of 2 Customly

Tags: java, math, natural-logarithm

I know I could generate it using `Math.log(2)` but I when I try to make up my own program to generate a natural log of 2 it continuously print 1. This is my code:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Ques11 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = scan.nextInt();
        BigDecimal sum = new BigDecimal(1);
        for(int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
            sum.add(new BigDecimal(1/n));
        }
        System.out.print(sum.setScale(10).toPlainString());
    }
}
```

I have tried to use `float`, `double` and `int` and in the end used `BigDecimal` but I still got 1 as the result I don't know why.

P.S It actually throws `InputMismatchException` when big numbers are given i.e greater than `2000000000` or `2 Billion`.

Comment: change `1/n` to `1.0/n`

Comment: Someone here to answer it?

Comment: What makes you think this computes the log of 2?  You seem to be computing `1 + (n-1) * 1/n` (once the integer division is corrected).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`n` is defined as an `int` and `1` is an `int` literal. When you divide two `int`s you use integer arithmetic, which would return only the whole part of the fraction - in your case, `0`.
To rectify this, you should use `double`s:

```
public class Ques11 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        double d = scan.nextInt(); // Note we're assigning to a double
        BigDecimal sum = new BigDecimal(1);
        for(int i = 2; i <= d; i++) {
            sum.add(new BigDecimal(1.0/d));
        }
        System.out.print(sum.setScale(10).toPlainString());
    }
}
```